# Looping through column_names with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model method, which creates a report for a questionnaire app. Each column in the table represents a different question, and each row is an interviewee. It uses the column_names method to create an array of question ids, and then add the relevant responses.

```
def self.import_answers(params)

@members = Member.where(:questionnaire_id => params[:questionnaire])
@columns = Report.column_names
@members.each do |member|
  @report = Report.find_by_membership_number(member.membership_number)
  @responses = Response.where(:member_id => member.id)
  @columns.each do |column|
    question = column.to_s.gsub("q", "").to_i
    @response = @responses.where(:question_id => question).first
    unless @response.nil?
      @report.column = @response.response_id
      @report.save
    end
  end
end
```

end

This method breaks at the line @report.column.

I think it could be because the column_names method returns an array of strings, like so...

```
["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10"]
```

This means that the line @report.column iterates like

```
@report."q1"
```

as opposed to...

```
@report.q1
```

which works.

I could be wrong about that! But either way, I am struggling to figure out how I can get it to work, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't show where `@report` is being defined. Also, can you add the exact error that occurs? Just reporting that it breaks is too ambiguous. What result are you expecting? Are you expecting that `@report` will be an array of interviewees that contains an array of questions and responses?

Comment: The reports table creates a row for each member. @report refers to a row (member) in the table. I have updated my question to show the full method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `send("#{atr}=")` to dynamically set an attribute. After reviewing your code you might be better off using `update_attribute` as it performs the `set` and `save` operations in one call.

I also noticed that you have the question `id` extraction logic outside the model. It might be better to encapsulate it in the Report model.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  # extract the question id from the column
  def self.column_question_id(name)
    name[1..-1].to_i
  end
end
```

Now your code can be written as:

```
Report.column_names do |column|
  @response = @responses.find_by_question_id(Report.column_question_id(column))  
  @report.update_attribute(column, @response.response_id) if @response.present?
end
```

Comment: Yes! This has worked perfectly. Though the update_attribute spelling did require an extra T, I won't hold that against you. Heaps of thanks, TICK!

Answer (score 0):

```
@report.send(column.to_sym) = @response.response_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`@report.send("#{column}=".to_sym, @response.response_id)`

You can get more info [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).